Loading information from a SQL DB to an array of buttons, they are not in order
I am writing a point-of-sale (POS) app where I have the layout number (1-35), text (price and product name) and image of the buttons in a SQL database. There is a ItemLayout table in the database, that includes the item ID (PLU), the layout number (1-35), if the button should be visible in the first place (all working) and the group of the item. They are read with the following function:
public ILMButtonsProps[] getILMButtonProps(string GroupName)
{
    ILMButtonsProps[] result = new ILMButtonsProps[getILMAmount(GroupName)];
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(returnConString());
        con.Open();

        string operation = "SELECT * FROM ItemLayout WHERE ItemGroup=@ItemGroup";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(operation, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ItemGroup", GroupName);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int count = 0;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result[count] = new ILMButtonsProps();
            result[count].ItemGroup = reader["ItemGroup"].ToString();
            result[count].LayoutNumber = reader["Number"].ToString();
            result[count].Enable = Convert.ToInt32(reader["Enable"].ToString());
            result[count].PLU = reader["PLU"].ToString();

            count++;
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        helperClass.throwError(ex.Message, ex.Source);
    }
    return result;
}

The function used to get the length for the array:
public int getILMAmount(string GroupName)
{
    int result = 0;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(returnConString());
        con.Open();

        string operation = "SELECT * FROM ItemLayout WHERE ItemGroup=@GroupName";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(operation, con);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroupName", GroupName);
        SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            result++;
        }
        reader.Close();
        con.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        helperClass.throwError(ex.Message, ex.Source);
    }
    return result;
}

And the class used (I don't think this is very important here but anyways:)
internal class  ILMButtonsProps
{
    internal string ItemGroup;
    internal string LayoutNumber;
    internal int Enable;
    internal string PLU;
}

Here is also the table in the table designer:

When I call the getILMButtonProps function using the next bit of code, I get all of the results in a weird pattern.
//Load buttons
ILMButtonsProps[] array = SQL.getILMButtonProps(cmbILMGroups.SelectedItem.ToString());
int counter = 0;
int max = array.Length;
Button[] btns = panel4.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray();

if (array == null)
{
    helperClass.throwError("There was an error reading the arrangements for the buttons in the database! Please try again...", "NPManager");
    return;
}

for (int x = 0; x < max; x++)
{
    //If all props are set, exit loop
    if (counter == max || counter == 35) { break; }

    //If there is a null in the layout, skip it.
    if (array[counter] == null)
    {
        counter++;
        return;
    }

    //Enable t/f
    //Get details from DB and input to buttons
    int i = Convert.ToInt32(array[counter].LayoutNumber);
    if (array[counter].Enable == 1)
    {
        btns[i].Text = "";
        btns[i].BackgroundImage = NPManager.Properties.Resources._109_AllAnnotations_Error_24x24_72;
    }

    if (array[counter].Enable == 2)
    {
        ILMDataPoints dp = SQL.getDataRowFromPLU(array[counter].PLU);

        btns[i].Text = dp.itemName + " @ " + dp.itemPrice;
        if(dp.image == null)
        {
            btns[i].BackgroundImage = null;
            btns[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
        if (dp.image != null && string.IsNullOrEmpty(dp.image.ToString()) && dp.image == System.DBNull.Value && dp.image.ToString() == "{}")
        {
            btns[i].BackgroundImage = GetImageFromByteArray((byte[])dp.image);

            PictureAnalysis pictureAnalysis = new PictureAnalysis();
            btns[i].ForeColor = GetReadableForeColor(pictureAnalysis.GetMostUsedColor(GetImageFromByteArray((byte[])dp.image))); //N
        }
    }

    counter++;
}

The ILMDatapoints (dp) variable is a custom class
Here is the result:

As you can see, the buttons arrangement is alternating from the top and bottom, but I want it to be from left to right. I don't understand how this is possible, as I am using multiple ways to ensure that the buttons and properties are in their correct order (numerical order). When I debug the the button array above, it shows that they're in the correct order, although I think this may be wrong, as I see it as the only point where the buttons could get messed up.

When you debug, what does the incorrect ordering first happen?  When you step through the while loop in getILMButtonProps, are records read from the database in the order you expect?  Or the order you're observing?

From the code side, everything looks good in terms of the incorrect ordering. Yes, the while loop is reading the records from the DB in the right order.

You pre-instanciate the buttons and then "just" fill them, right? How do you do that? Is it hard-coded? Either way, you get those in the order panel4.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToArray() is giving them to you. If iterating that array is giving you odd / seemingly random results in order, than it's here, where you need to intervene. You could / should find a way to sort that array before iterating it.

Btw. I think it would be more convenient to replace if (counter == max || counter == 35) { break; } with initializing max with var max = Math.Min( array.Length, btns.Length );

By the way, instead of iterating over the result of a query just to see how many there are, use a SELECT COUNT(*). Or fill a List<ILMButtonsProps> instead of an array that needs to be preallocated

You need to add an ORDER BY to your query if you want the results in a specific order.

For anyone in the future who needs the solution, it is to sort the buttons in the btns[]
Here is what I did:
Button[] btns = panel4.Controls.Cast<Button>().OrderBy(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Tag)).ToArray();
Here is the result:

I used the tag on the buttons to make this possible.
Thank you to Fildor (see comment on problem above) and Lân Vũ for the solution.

Try ordering by the layoutnumber in the SQL query

Tried that, didn't work. Thank you the suggestion.
